# I want to delete IAM users with a script which have a prefix "vault-" to them and are older than 2 days

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, amazon-iam, aws-cli

How do I list IAM users with aws cli which are older than 2 days and a prefix attached to them?

Comment: You can probably do this using the `--query` option to filter (and select which node(s) you want) and the `--output` option to control what you see. But you may be better off writing a few lines of boto3 that iterates and programmatically selects what you want. The result will be easier to read and maintain (JMESPath is slick but not always intuitive) but more extensible in the future for other tasks.

Comment: As the output will be in json, jq is another option

Comment: Sorry, I should have added this before.
aws iam list-users --output table --query 'Users[*].UserName'

How do I query it with date created and then filter with only the users created two days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aws iam list-users | jq '.Users[] | select ( .CreateDate | contains("2019-10-10") ) | select ( .UserName | startswith("vault-") ) | .UserId'
```

and then you can loop over results to delete the user

Comment: Hey @Tomek Klas thanks for the response. This really is helpful. Now there's a twist. Can we find the users which start with "vault-" and are not the latest? So if randomly we have users get created with "vault-" and we want to delete all but the latest because we don't know when was the last time the user got created. I think this needs sorting and finding the last CreateDate and chuck out that user. But don't know the syntax for the code.